# Warning: The ticklabel anchor cannot be determined, the normal vector and the unit x vector are almost parallel

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I recently created a particular figure using `pgfplots`, the code of which is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows              ,
    calc                ,
    pgfplots.fillbetween,
    positioning         ,
    }%
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=16cm,vscale=0.75,vcentering]{geometry}


% PGFPlot version compatibility settings
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering

        % Phase lag
        \newcommand*{\Lag}{pi/2}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                legend entries = {$x_{1}(t) = A\cos(\omega{t})$, $x_{2}(t) = A\cos(\omega{t} - \phi)$},
                legend cell align = {left},
                width   = \textwidth,
                view    = {45}{30},
                xlabel  = $t$,
                zlabel  = $x(t)$,
                xtick   = {0, 1.57, 3.14, 4.71, 6.28},
                ytick   = \empty,
                ztick   = {-1, 1},
                xticklabels = {$0$, $0.5\pi$, $\pi$, $1.5\pi$, $2\pi$},
                zticklabels = {$-A$, $A$},
                xmin    = 0,
                xmax    = 2*pi,
                ymin    = -1.1,
                ymax    = 1.1,
                zmin    = -1.2,
                zmax    = 1.4,
                axis lines       = center,
                axis line style  = {->},
                axis equal image = true,
                hide y axis,
                every axis x label/.style={%
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=west,
                },
                every axis z label/.style={%
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=south,
                }]
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    thick
                    ]%
                    (x, 0, {cos(deg(x))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    dashdotted,
                    thick
                    ]%
                    (x, 0, {cos(deg(x - \Lag))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    very thin
                    ]%
                    (0, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    very thin
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});

                % Draw angle
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0.5*pi:pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {0.25*cos(deg(x))}, {0.25*sin(deg(x))});

                \node at (axis cs:0.75*\Lag,0,0) {$\phi$};

                % Clipping path A
                \addplot3[%
                    name path=A,
                    draw=none,
                    domain=0.5*pi:pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});

                % Clipping path B
                \draw[%
                    name path=B,
                    ->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:\Lag,0,0) -- (axis cs:\Lag,-1,0);
                \draw[%
                    dashed
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:\Lag,0,0) -- (axis cs:\Lag,0,1);
                \draw[%
                    <->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:\Lag,0,1);
                \draw[%
                    ->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:0,0,1);

                \node at (axis cs:0.5*\Lag,0.75,1) {$t_{0} = \displaystyle\frac{\phi}{\omega}$};

                % Fill area spanned by the angle \phi
                \addplot[%
                    gray,
                    opacity=0.5
                    ] fill between[%
                    of=A and B,
                    ];
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-1.5cm}
        \caption{Phase lag and time lag of a sinusoidal function relative to the cosine function.}
        \label{fig:PLTLSF}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiling the figure either on its own or with multiple copies of itself into a PDF file is fine. However, the problem is that this figure screws up the positioning of x-axis labels of every other figures that uses `\addplot3` in the same document if it is the first figure that appears, i.e. if its code precedes the code of every other figures. Otherwise, its own x-axis labels are messed up. In both cases, the compiler indicates the following warning in the log:

```
Package pgfplots Warning: the ticklabel anchor cannot be determined, the normal
vector -(-0.62286pt,0.78468pt) and the unit x vector (0.89452pt,-0.4472pt) are
almost parallel (abs(cos(angle)) = 0.90807pt)! on input line 227.
[warning /pgfplots/warning/ticklabel anchor undetermined]
```

For example, in the following code, the above-mentioned figure is placed *after* an arbitrary figure that uses `\addplot3`. So, the alignment of its own x-axis labels is expected to be erroneous:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows              ,
    calc                ,
    pgfplots.fillbetween,
    positioning         ,
    }%
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=16cm,vscale=0.75,vcentering]{geometry}


% PGFPlot version compatibility settings
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering

        % Definition of plane
        \newcommand*{\PointAx}{1}%
        \newcommand*{\PointAy}{1}%
        \newcommand*{\PointAz}{1}%
        \newcommand*{\PointAc}{0}%

        % Normal vector scaling
        \newcommand*{\ScaleN}{1}%

        % Endpoints of line segment spanned by the normal vector
        \newcommand*{\ScaleB}{6}%

        % Position of the label of plane
        \newcommand*{\PointLx}{-0.9}%
        \newcommand*{\PointLy}{-0.9}%

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                view    = {115}{30},
                xlabel  = $x$,
                ylabel  = $y$,
                zlabel  = $z$,
                xtick   = \empty,
                ytick   = \empty,
                ztick   = \empty,
                width   = 15cm,
                axis lines      = center,
                axis line style = {->, white!50!black},
                axis equal      = true,
                ]

                % Equation of line
                \coordinate (P1) at (axis cs: \ScaleB*\PointAx, \ScaleB*\PointAy, \ScaleB*\PointAz);
                \coordinate (P2) at (axis cs:-\ScaleB*\PointAx, -\ScaleB*\PointAy, -\ScaleB*\PointAz);
                \draw[white!25!green] (P1) -- (P2);

                % Plane ax + by + cz = d <=> z = 1/c * (-ax - by + d)
                \addplot3[%
                    fill    = white!75!blue,
                    opacity = 0.5,
                    draw    = blue
                    ] coordinates {%
                    (2, 0, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*2 - (\PointAy)*0 + \PointAc)})
                    (0, -2, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*0 - (\PointAy)*(-2) + \PointAc)})
                    (-2, 0, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*(-2) - (\PointAy)*0 + \PointAc)})
                    (0, 2, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*0 - (\PointAy)*2 + \PointAc)})
                    (2, 0, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*2 - (\PointAy)*0 + \PointAc)})
                    };

                % Overpainting correction for the line and the z-axis
                \coordinate (O) at (axis cs: 0, 0, 0);
                \draw[white!25!green] (O) -- (P1);
                \draw[->, white!50!black] (axis cs: 0, 0, \PointAc) -- (axis cs: 0, 0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax});


                % Specify normal vector coordinates
                \coordinate (N) at (axis cs: \ScaleN*\PointAx, \ScaleN*\PointAy, \ScaleN*\PointAz);

                % Draw vectors
                \draw[->, >=stealth, thick] (O) -- (N);

                % Draw labels
                \draw (O) node [anchor=north] {$\boldsymbol{\mathbf{0}}$};
                \draw (N) node [anchor=south] {$\boldsymbol{\mathbf{n}}$};
                \draw (P1) node [anchor=south west] {$L$};
                \draw ([xshift=-30mm] axis cs: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}) node [anchor=north east] {$\mathbb{R}^{3}$};
                \draw (axis cs: \PointLx, \PointLy, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*\PointLx - (\PointAy)*\PointLy + \PointAc)}) node {$\Pi$};
             \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Typical subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$---the entire space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, the plane $\Pi$, the line $L$ spanned by the normal vector of $\Pi$, and the singleton consisting of the zero vector.}
        \label{fig:subspaces_in_r3}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering

        % Phase lag
        \newcommand*{\Lag}{pi/2}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                legend entries = {$x_{1}(t) = A\cos(\omega{t})$, $x_{2}(t) = A\cos(\omega{t} - \phi)$},
                legend cell align = {left},
                width   = \textwidth,
                view    = {45}{30},
                xlabel  = $t$,
                zlabel  = $x(t)$,
                xtick   = {0, 1.57, 3.14, 4.71, 6.28},
                ytick   = \empty,
                ztick   = {-1, 1},
                xticklabels = {$0$, $0.5\pi$, $\pi$, $1.5\pi$, $2\pi$},
                zticklabels = {$-A$, $A$},
                xmin    = 0,
                xmax    = 2*pi,
                ymin    = -1.1,
                ymax    = 1.1,
                zmin    = -1.2,
                zmax    = 1.4,
                axis lines       = center,
                axis line style  = {->},
                axis equal image = true,
                hide y axis,
                every axis x label/.style={%
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=west,
                },
                every axis z label/.style={%
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=south,
                }]
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    thick
                    ]%
                    (x, 0, {cos(deg(x))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    dashdotted,
                    thick
                    ]%
                    (x, 0, {cos(deg(x - \Lag))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    very thin
                    ]%
                    (0, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    very thin
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});

                % Draw angle
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0.5*pi:pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {0.25*cos(deg(x))}, {0.25*sin(deg(x))});

                \node at (axis cs:0.75*\Lag,0,0) {$\phi$};

                % Clipping path A
                \addplot3[%
                    name path=A,
                    draw=none,
                    domain=0.5*pi:pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});

                % Clipping path B
                \draw[%
                    name path=B,
                    ->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:\Lag,0,0) -- (axis cs:\Lag,-1,0);
                \draw[%
                    dashed
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:\Lag,0,0) -- (axis cs:\Lag,0,1);
                \draw[%
                    <->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:\Lag,0,1);
                \draw[%
                    ->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:0,0,1);

                \node at (axis cs:0.5*\Lag,0.75,1) {$t_{0} = \displaystyle\frac{\phi}{\omega}$};

                % Fill area spanned by the angle \phi
                \addplot[%
                    gray,
                    opacity=0.5
                    ] fill between[%
                    of=A and B,
                    ];
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-1.5cm}
        \caption{Phase lag and time lag of a sinusoidal function relative to the cosine function.}
        \label{fig:PLTLSF}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output with the above-mentioned warning:

[image]

Notice that the positioning of the x-axis labels in Figure 2 is not right. I suspect there is something wrong with the code of that figure, but I cannot pinpoint exactly what is wrong. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

### Update

Ok, I commented out the line `view = {45}{30}` and the warning disappears, so does the problem with the alignment.

So, the question now becomes: how can I circumvent the problem with the positioning of the x-axis labels if the line `view = {45}{30}` is essential for my purpose?

### Update 2

Further tests suggest that the problem occurs only when both the `axis` options `axis lines = center` and `view = {<azimuth>}{<elevation>}` are used in a set of two or more figures in a single document, and only with certain range of value assigned to the first argument, i.e. the `<azimuth>`. Notably, the problem does *not* occur if

- the value of `<azimuth>` of *all* the figures is within the range of 0 < angle < 90;
- the value of `<azimuth>` of *all* the figures is over 90;
- the value of `<azimuth>` of certain figures is over 90, and the rest lie between 0 < angle < 25; or
- the axes of all the figures, except those of the last, are hidden, as suggested by [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t)

The problem occurs if

- the value of `<azimuth>` of the first few figures is over 90, and the rest lie between 25 < angle < 90,

as is the case in the above-mentioned example, in which the `view` setting of Figure 1 is `view = {115}{30}` and that of Figure 2 is `view = {45}{30}`.

Answer (score 2):

That was odd. I have no idea why this happens, but I note that it also appears to be connected to `axis lines=center` in the first diagram. Remove that and the warning goes away. Hence, a potential workaround would be to use `hide axis` for the first diagram, and then draw the axis lines manually with `\draw`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[hang]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows              ,
    calc                ,
    pgfplots.fillbetween,
    positioning         ,
    }%
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=16cm,vscale=0.75,vcentering]{geometry}


% PGFPlot version compatibility settings
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering

        % Definition of plane
        \newcommand*{\PointAx}{1}%
        \newcommand*{\PointAy}{1}%
        \newcommand*{\PointAz}{1}%
        \newcommand*{\PointAc}{0}%

        % Normal vector scaling
        \newcommand*{\ScaleN}{1}%

        % Endpoints of line segment spanned by the normal vector
        \newcommand*{\ScaleB}{6}%

        % Position of the label of plane
        \newcommand*{\PointLx}{-0.9}%
        \newcommand*{\PointLy}{-0.9}%

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                view    = {115}{30},
                xlabel  = $x$,
                ylabel  = $y$,
                zlabel  = $z$,
                xtick   = \empty,
                ytick   = \empty,
                ztick   = \empty,
                width   = 15cm,
                hide axis, % <-- added
%                axis lines      = center,
%                axis line style = {->, white!50!black},
                axis equal      = true,
                ]
                % draw axes manually
                \draw [->, white!50!black]
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0,0) --
                    (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0,0) node[above]{$x$};
                \draw [->, white!50!black]
                    (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin},0) --
                    (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax},0) node[above]{$y$};
                \draw [->, white!50!black]
                    (0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmin}) --
                    (0,0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}) node[right]{$z$};

%                % Equation of line
                \coordinate (P1) at (axis cs: \ScaleB*\PointAx, \ScaleB*\PointAy, \ScaleB*\PointAz);
                \coordinate (P2) at (axis cs:-\ScaleB*\PointAx, -\ScaleB*\PointAy, -\ScaleB*\PointAz);
                \draw[white!25!green] (P1) -- (P2);

                % Plane ax + by + cz = d <=> z = 1/c * (-ax - by + d)
                    \addplot3[%
                        fill    = white!75!blue,
                        opacity = 0.5,
                        draw    = blue
                        ] coordinates {%
                        (2, 0, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*2 - (\PointAy)*0 + \PointAc)})
                        (0, -2, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*0 - (\PointAy)*(-2) + \PointAc)})
                        (-2, 0, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*(-2) - (\PointAy)*0 + \PointAc)})
                        (0, 2, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*0 - (\PointAy)*2 + \PointAc)})
                        (2, 0, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*2 - (\PointAy)*0 + \PointAc)})
                        };

                % Overpainting correction for the line and the z-axis
                \coordinate (O) at (axis cs: 0, 0, 0);
                \draw[white!25!green] (O) -- (P1);
                \draw[->, white!50!black] (axis cs: 0, 0, \PointAc) -- (axis cs: 0, 0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax});


                % Specify normal vector coordinates
                \coordinate (N) at (axis cs: \ScaleN*\PointAx, \ScaleN*\PointAy, \ScaleN*\PointAz);

                % Draw vectors
                \draw[->, >=stealth, thick] (O) -- (N);

                % Draw labels
                \draw (O) node [anchor=north] {$\boldsymbol{\mathbf{0}}$};
                \draw (N) node [anchor=south] {$\boldsymbol{\mathbf{n}}$};
                \draw (P1) node [anchor=south west] {$L$};
                \draw ([xshift=-30mm] axis cs: \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/zmax}) node [anchor=north east] {$\mathbb{R}^{3}$};
                \draw (axis cs: \PointLx, \PointLy, {(1/\PointAz)*(-(\PointAx)*\PointLx - (\PointAy)*\PointLy + \PointAc)}) node {$\Pi$};
             \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Typical subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$---the entire space $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, the plane $\Pi$, the line $L$ spanned by the normal vector of $\Pi$, and the singleton consisting of the zero vector.}
        \label{fig:subspaces_in_r3}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \centering

        % Phase lag
        \newcommand*{\Lag}{pi/2}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                legend entries = {$x_{1}(t) = A\cos(\omega{t})$, $x_{2}(t) = A\cos(\omega{t} - \phi)$},
                legend cell align = {left},
                width   = \textwidth,
                view    = {45}{30},
                xlabel  = $t$,
                zlabel  = $x(t)$,
                xtick   = {0, 1.57, 3.14, 4.71, 6.28},
                ytick   = \empty,
                ztick   = {-1, 1},
                xticklabels = {$0$, $0.5\pi$, $\pi$, $1.5\pi$, $2\pi$},
                zticklabels = {$-A$, $A$},
                xmin    = 0,
                xmax    = 2*pi,
                ymin    = -1.1,
                ymax    = 1.1,
                zmin    = -1.2,
                zmax    = 1.4,
                axis lines       = center,
                axis line style  = {->},
                axis equal image = true,
                hide y axis,
                every axis x label/.style={%
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=west,
                },
                every axis z label/.style={%
                    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.02)},
                    anchor=south,
                }]
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    thick
                    ]%
                    (x, 0, {cos(deg(x))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    dashdotted,
                    thick
                    ]%
                    (x, 0, {cos(deg(x - \Lag))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    very thin
                    ]%
                    (0, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0:2*pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black,
                    very thin
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});

                % Draw angle
                \addplot3[%
                    domain=0.5*pi:pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    color=black
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {0.25*cos(deg(x))}, {0.25*sin(deg(x))});

                \node at (axis cs:0.75*\Lag,0,0) {$\phi$};

                % Clipping path A
                \addplot3[%
                    name path=A,
                    draw=none,
                    domain=0.5*pi:pi,
                    samples=100,
                    samples y=0,
                    ]%
                    (\Lag, {cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))});

                % Clipping path B
                \draw[%
                    name path=B,
                    ->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:\Lag,0,0) -- (axis cs:\Lag,-1,0);
                \draw[%
                    dashed
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:\Lag,0,0) -- (axis cs:\Lag,0,1);
                \draw[%
                    <->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:\Lag,0,1);
                \draw[%
                    ->,
                    >=stealth
                    ]%
                    (axis cs:0,0,1) -- (axis cs:0,0,1);

                \node at (axis cs:0.5*\Lag,0.75,1) {$t_{0} = \displaystyle\frac{\phi}{\omega}$};

                % Fill area spanned by the angle \phi
                \addplot[%
                    gray,
                    opacity=0.5
                    ] fill between[%
                    of=A and B,
                    ];
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \vspace{-1.5cm}
        \caption{Phase lag and time lag of a sinusoidal function relative to the cosine function.}
        \label{fig:PLTLSF}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a workaround. I'm not sure how a locally defined parameter like `axis lines=center` in a scope block can affect another scope block. I dug further into the problem and found some peculiar connections between `axis lines=center` and `view={<azimuth>}{<elevation>}`, and updated my post with some new findings accordingly. Hopefully the code maintainer(s) of `pgfplots`will also be notified about this problem.

Comment: @PYK No, that was what I found odd as well. Christian Feuersänger (`pgfplots` maintainer) does visit this site, but to make sure he knows about it, you could report it at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/?source=navbar